# Regular Expression with grep or sed does not work

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed, grep

I'd like to use regular expression using linux command "grep".
Currently I have file which looks like this..

```
X.54(val)(08)(15)(4)
(32)(0.001)(77)(90)
X.54(val)(08)(15)(4)
(33)(0.001)(77)(90)
X.54(val)(08)(15)(4)
(34)(0.001)(77)(90)
```

My goal is using a regex which gives me following result

```
X.54(val)(08)(15)(4)
(32)
X.54(val)(08)(15)(4)
(33)
X.54(val)(08)(15)(4)
(34)
```

Currently I'm using this regex

```
(^\((.*?)\))
```

which works on https://regexr.com/ fine but using 
command "grep" or "sed" does not work...

```
sed -e '/(^\((.*?)\))/gm'
grep '/(^\((.*?)\))/gm'
```

Can somebody help me....?

Thanks in advance,
Markus

Comment: What are the rules to obtain the result you want?

Comment: POSIX Basic Regular Expressions, like sed and plain grep use, does not support `?`.

Comment: And iwith grep, that `/` and `/gm` looks for those literal strings as part of the regular expression....

Answer (score 1):

Here is one for `grep`:

```
$ grep -o "^\(([^)]*)\|[^(].*\)" file
```

Output:

```
X.54(val)(08)(15)(4)
(32)
X.54(val)(08)(15)(4)
(33)
X.54(val)(08)(15)(4)
(34)
```

Basically, *output from the beginning* `([^)]*)` *or* `[^(].*`

Answer (score 1):

This is a `sed` solution:

```
sed '/^[^X]/s/\(([0-9]*)\).*/\1/' yourfile
```

where

- `/^[^X]/` will limit the scope of the following command (`s`) to the lines matching the pattern `^[^X]`,
- `s` is the substitution command,
- `\(([0-9]*)\).*` is the matched regexp (0 or more digits between parenthesis, followed by any characters), a part of which is captured by `\(\)`
- and `\1` is the substitution string consiting of the text captured by the first `\(\)` group

Clearly you can refine the command (simplifying it or making it more complex) depending on whether your example is general enough or not.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^X/!s/).*/)/' file
```

If a line does not begin with `X` replace everything from the first `)` to the end of the line with `)`.